# AccountInfo -> Signer for CPI calls

Tags: cpi, anchor

What is the best way to transform an AccountInfo into a Signer for CPI calls?
Is there another way I should be thinking about this?

My signer in this case is a PDA, which cannot sign the initial call to my program.

Answer (score 3):

There's a specific instruction to [invoke a CPI with a PDA signer](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#program-signed-accounts).

Specifically you need to call `invoke_signed()` with the relevant PDA seeds. The Solana runtime will internally handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do the trick:

`Signer::try_from(&self.my_account.to_account_info()).unwrap()`

Comment: The `Signer` trait is about creating new signatures, which is not possible on-chain, and also not possible for PDAs.  You'll need to use `invoke_signed` as @yamen's answer points out